# Connect Django Postgres to AWS RDS over SSL

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ssl

I'm digging into Django and thought it would be a nice exercise to connect to an AWS RDS database over SSL, but I can't quite figure out how to provide the SSL-cert from AWS to the database config.

I've downloaded the `global-bundle.pem` from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html.

Now in the Django source code, it seems you can pass these parameters to `DATABASES`:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sslmode': 'verify-ca',
            'sslrootcert': 'root.crt',
            'sslcert': 'client.crt',
            'sslkey': 'client.key',
        },
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I convert/pass the certificate from AWS?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just do something like

```
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sslmode': 'verify-full',
            'sslrootcert': 'global-bundle.pem'
        },
```